# Let $\mathbb F$ be field with $16807=7^5$ elements.What is the cardinality of the set given by $\{a^7-b^7:a,b\in \mathbb F\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, field-theory, permutations

> Let $\mathbb F$ be field with $16807=7^5$ elements.What is the
>   cardinality of the set given by $\{a^7-b^7:a,b\in \mathbb F\}$?

how to approach this problem?

Comment: @DietrichBurde:Is it $7^5?$

Comment: It can't be less, by taking, say $b=0$. Can it be more?

Comment: @DietrichBurde:What result you used to conclude $x^7=x$  for $x≠0$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: $x^7=x$ even if $x=0$ (and even if the characteristic is not $7$).

Comment: I just meant that $0^7=0$ in any field or ring…

Comment: @DietrichBurde:If $a\neq 0$ and $b=0$,then there are $7^5$ choices for $a$.If $a\neq 0$ and $b=1$,then there are $7^5$ choices for $a$.If $b=2$,then there are $7^5$ choices for $a$.Repeating the same we would go through $7^5$ cases.On interchanging the role of $a $ and $b$,we again can have $7^5 $ cases.
In total there are $2\times 7^5$ cases.So the cardinality is  **$2\times 7^5$**?

Comment: These choices are not always different. The cardinality asked here, I think, is without repetitions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, are you really in your first comment saying that the non-zero elements of this field of 16807 elements all have orders dividing $6$. (Should it be $x^7\not=x$ for $x\not=0$?)

Comment: Sorry, I am not with you, @DietrichBurde. In the field of $4$ elements we do not have $x^2=x$ for all $x$ we have $x^4=x$ for all $x$. That doesn't stop $x\mapsto x^p$ being injective, though.

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are completely right (sorry), I wanted to say that the Frobenius is surjective (injective and finitely many elements).

Answer (score 1):

First of all notice, that $a^7-b^7 = a^7+(-b)^7 = (a-b)^7$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$ according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream , this means that
$$\{ a^7-b^7 \: | \: a,b \in \mathbb{F} \} = \{x^7 | x\in \mathbb{F}\}$$ 
Now $x\mapsto x^7$ is a ring homomorphism (this is again a consequence of freshmans dream), and if we can prove that it is injective, then we must have $|\{x^7 | x\in \mathbb{F}\}|=|\mathbb{F}|$. Suppose therefore that $a^7=b^7$. Then $a^7-b^7 = (a-b)^7 = 0$, which means that $a=b$ proving injectivity.